# How to move completed torrent downloads to another folder without breaking the torrent link?

Tags: files, file-sharing, download

I'm using Transmission on EOs and I've downloaded a bunch of torrent files which ended up my Download folder in my /home.

I'd like now to move the files to my external hard drive without breaking the link and contribute to further sharing upload of these files.

What should I do?

Comment: Move the entire torrent download folder to your external HD(`mv /home/user/Download/torrent /media/torrent`) and create a symlink (`ln -s /media/torrent /home/user/Download/torrent`)

Comment: Maybe Transmission has a setting for where it looks for torrent files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to select all torrents in Transmission, then go to the menu *Torrent > Set Location* and then choose the desired location for torrents. After which, Transmission takes care of moving torrents.

Comment: This still works in 2024. It might look like nothing is happening if your server is under high load and can take several hours to complete. Not sure why, since moving files only changes references and does not actually copy data.

Answer (score 1):

You can move them and change their destination folders in torrent client to a new ones. Then run recheck Torrent menu >> Verify Local Data and torrents should find your files in new folder.

Comment: Is it file specific or doesn't this change the torrent location for *all* the torrents in consequence (which would be undesirable)?

Comment: I've found one needn't re-verify, just restart the client after the move and it takes the files as normal

Answer (score 0):

For Transmissions 4 or higher:

Select the Torrent. Go to `File > Move data file to...` Select the folder you want to move your data to.

If you have already moved your data, use the same step but after that use `Verify local data` (right click on the torrent or `Transfers > Verify local data`)